# Saltstack Dynamic Pillar Data

Tags: salt-stack

I have several servers that have an application deployed on them and I would like to store the application version as a pillar.  It is possible to parse a file on the server to extract this information and it will change occasionally when the application is upgraded.  I had thought that this might work:

```
version: {{ salt['cmd.run']('cat myfile | grep version') }}
```

But instead it appears to run the cmd.run from the master.  What would be the method for creating this kind of dynamic pillar data?

Answer (score -1):

So, pillar data is rendered on the master, as such complex dynamic things in pillar can over whelm a master if there are a lot of them and minions are always requesting them. so to do anything that needs to be gathered from a minion needs to be targeted at a minion. which is going to cause a slowdown in pillar and up the render time for pillar.

pillar data should be secrets. using something like map.jinja for things like what you are talking about is a better way to go about it. that way it is rendered on the minion. if other servers need the information there is salt mine which allows minions to query what other minions have.